# iOS deleting all app sandbox data automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-sandbox

I have a very strange issue that has been occurring to a few users of my app. One of the users actually described the issue to me.

My app downloads magazine data to the device to allow for offline reading. This means that users can sometimes have around 10 gigs+ downloaded to the device.

The problem this user experienced (and a few others have too) is that randomly all sandbox data gets deleted from the app (included core data files). The user told me that he was downloading something in a different app and got the "Storage Almost Full - You can manage your storage in Settings" popup message.

He went to the settings app and went to General > Usage. He then saw the app was using around 13 gigs of data. While he was in that list he said every time he went out of the Usage tab, then back in the app's data was getting smaller and smaller. Until eventually the app said it was using 0mb.

When he logged back into the app all his data was deleted and core data was also removed which lead the app to think he was a completely new user with no data downloaded.

I then ran some tests on my own where I made sure my device only had 100mb of space available. I then started downloading in the app. The warning message popped up alerting me I was running out of space and I ignored it and continued downloading. I have now downloaded about 1.5 gigs of data and am still downloading and the device seems like it is freeing up space somewhere else to make room for my downloads.

I've searched far and wide and have found no one else ever experiencing a problem like this. So my questions are:

1. Has anyone else every experienced this issue before?
2. Does Apple have a policy that will remove app data from the app that uses the most space if the device is running out of space?
3. Is there an algorythm that decides which app will get cleared when space is running out?
4. Is there a way to tell the OS not to remove data when running out of space?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're storing the data in the `caches` subdirectory:

> On iOS 5.0 and later, the system may delete the Caches directory on
>   rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will
>   never occur while an app is running. However, you should be aware that
>   iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the
>   Caches directory can be erased.

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm 98% sure that this is the issue as the previous developers where saving both the database and files in the Caches directory and a very small percentage of our users have had this issue